# Where do I import the `DoesNotExist` exception in Django 1.10 from?

Tags: django, python-3.x, exception

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I'm trying to catch an exception in the case of a specific object not existing, but the line

```
from django.core.exceptions import DoesNotExist
```

gives me the `cannot find reference in exeptions.py` warning. If the exception is not specified in that file, where do I find it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The exception is called [`ObjectDoesNotExists` <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist) in case the model is not known, so you import it as:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
```

The `Object` is used to avoid confusion with the `DoesNotExist` exception every model has (you can see `Object` as a "generalization" of objects of all models).

Note however that if you *know* what the model is of the model that you query for, it is better to use a *more restricted* exception, like:

```
try:
    SomeModel.objects.get(pk=14)
except SomeModel.DoesNotExist:
    # ... do something
    pass
```

Like specified in the documentation of the [model attributes <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#doesnotexist):

> Django provides **a `DoesNotExist` exception as an attribute of each model class** to identify the class of object that could not be found and to allow you to **catch a particular model class** with try/except. The exception is a subclass of [`django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist).

Such that you do not - by accident - catch exceptions because some (related) model can not be fetched. Typically the span of a `try`-`except` block should be as small as possible, and the exception as "explicit" as possible.

Comment: Do I need to define the `DoesNotExist` exception within my model myself? PyCharm CE is complaining about an `unresolved attribute reference for class MyClass` when I try to use the `SomeModel.DoesNotExist` alternative.

Comment: No, every *model* (not every class, only Django models) have a `DoesNotExist` exception added to these.

Comment: So this might just be a case of PyCharm CE being pissy about the syntax, since only the commercial edition has support for Django.

Comment: @TheSodesa: I think the CE edition has no Django plugin. PyCharm professional has some extra tooling that can resolve attributes that Django adds to the models dynamically (and typically not picked up by a standard program analysis).

Comment: Pycharm commercial here with everything else setup for Django.. still complains :-/

Comment: @dangel: did you specify the virtual environment that you use and where Django is installed?

Answer (score 6):

It should be [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
```

You can also catch exception for specific model like this:

```
from .your_models import ModelClass

ModelClass.DoesNotExist
```